# How should I format a socket.io message to send to node.js from a Perl script?

Tags: javascript, perl, node.js, socket.io

I have a simple node.js server using socket.io that's listening for messages.  I'm sending messages to the server from a Perl script - The server seems to be receiving the messages, but not recognizing the "channel" of the message.  How do I correctly construct node.js/socket.io messages to be sent from a Perl script?

Here's my node.js server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("In connection");
  socket.on('testevent', function (data) {
    console.log("In testevent");
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Here's part of my Perl script which sends the message:

```
#$clientID is set to 1598760311220985572 earlier... obtained from a handshake

$uri = "http://192.168.3.13:3000/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/$clientID";

$message = "5:::{'name':'testevent','args':['hello!']}";

$request = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );
$request->content( $message );

print $response = $browser->request( $request )->as_string;
```

Server log after message received from Perl script:

```
  info  - handshake authorized 1598760311220985572
  debug - client authorized for 
In connection
  debug - xhr-polling received data packet 5:::{'name':'testevent','args':['hello!']}
```

So, the node.js server seems to be receiving the message, but not recognizing the channel "testevent", because I would expect the server to log the string "In testevent" if it interpreted the message correctly.

Am I formatting my message correctly in Perl, or maybe my server code is wrong?

Comment: You could use plain TCP. It looks like there's a perl library for socket.io called PocketIO, but it might not be directly interoperable, I haven't checked. It probably is. But you should probably use [TCP](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Comment: This is interesting. Where did you come up with the JSON syntax for the content, specifically the `5:::`? And does socket.io require a `header()` before the content when POST'ing (vs. `socket.emit()`)?